# Boton formulario

Tags: php, mysql

Tengo una página con un formulario en el que hay que rellenar el campo usuario y seleccionar un ingrediente con select. Tengo que comprobar que el usuario que se introduce está en la base de datos. Si no, me saldrá el siguiente echo y un botón para volver atrás:

```
$usuario=$_POST['usuario'];
 if( !( $usuario == "" ) ){
     $consulta="SELECT * FROM usuario WHERE usuario = '$usuario'";
     $resultado=mysqli_query($con, $consulta);
     $con=mysqli_num_rows($resultado);
     if($con == 0){
        echo"Usuario inexistente. Introduzca un usuario registrado";
    }else{
        $con==1;
    }
    echo"
    <form action=\"http://localhost/PROYECTO/pedirPlato.php\">
    <div class=\"boton\"><input type=\"submit\" value=\"Vuelve\"/></div>
    /form>
    ";
}
```

El caso es que cuando introduzco un usuario que sí está en la base de datos y ademas selecciono un ingrediente, tengo que colocar un botón diferente para que me lleve a otra página. Código:

```
if (isset($_POST['ingrediente']) && ($con == 1)){

    $resultadoConsulta="SELECT apellidos FROM usuario WHERE usuario = '$usuario'";
    $sql=mysqli_query($con, $resultadoConsulta);

            $fila=  mysqli_fetch_assoc($sql);
            while ($fila != null){
                $fila['apellidos'];
                echo "Apellidos: " .$fila['apellidos'];
                $fila= mysqli_fetch_assoc($sql);
            }
     echo"
    <form action=\"http://localhost/PROYECTO/pagar.php\">
    <div class=\"boton2\"><input type=\"submit\" value=\"Haz el pago\"/></div>
    /form>
    ";
}
```

El problema que tengo es que al agregar este último trozo de código me aparecen los dos botones, cuando solo me tendría que salir el último "Haz el pago" y no el de arriba "Vuelve". Donde debería colocar el primer botón para que no se repita?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Primero, si el usuario no está en la BBDD y quieres que te salga el botón "Vuelve" sería:

```
$usuario=$_POST['usuario'];
 if( !( $usuario == "" ) ){
     $consulta="SELECT * FROM usuario WHERE usuario = '$usuario'";
     $resultado=mysqli_query($con, $consulta);
     $con=mysqli_num_rows($resultado);
     if($con == 0){
        echo"Usuario inexistente. Introduzca un usuario registrado";
        echo "<form action=\"http://localhost/PROYECTO/pedirPlato.php\">
        <div class=\"boton\"><input type=\"submit\" value=\"Vuelve\"/></div>
        /form>";
     }else{
        $con=1;
     }
}
```

Luego si el usuario sí está en la BBDD y quieres el otro código sería:

```
if (isset($_POST['ingrediente']) && ($con == 1)){
    $resultadoConsulta="SELECT apellidos FROM usuario WHERE usuario = '$usuario'";
    $sql=mysqli_query($con, $resultadoConsulta);
    $fila=  mysqli_fetch_assoc($sql);
            while ($fila != null){
                $fila['apellidos'];
                echo "Apellidos: " .$fila['apellidos'];
                $fila= mysqli_fetch_assoc($sql);
            }
     echo"
    <form action=\"http://localhost/PROYECTO/pagar.php\">
    <div class=\"boton2\"><input type=\"submit\" value=\"Haz el pago\"/></div>
    /form>
    ";
}
```

Comment: Hola @LuisOrtega muchas gracias por responder, lo he probado pero me sigue saliendo el botón de vuelve cuando el usuario está en la base de datos además del otro...Hay algun sitio más donde probar ponerlo?

Comment: Hola, de nada. Viendo el codigo, deberia estar `$con=0;` antes del todo el codigo, luego, cambiaria `if( !( $usuario == "" ) )` por `if(!empty($usuario))`. Ademas te recomendaria hacer un var_dump de esta linea  `$con=mysqli_num_rows($resultado);` y ver que valor esta tomando esa variable. Puedes poner el codigo en github o en pastebin para verlo.

Comment: Ya está solucionado mil gracias @LuisOrtega

Answer (score 0):

Puedes hacer que el boton se muestre, y cuando el usuario exista en la bd que el boton se oculte:

Código:

```
$tipo = "button";  //ya que de momento es un boton visible
$usuario=$_POST['usuario'];
 if( !( $usuario == "" ) ){
     $consulta="SELECT * FROM usuario WHERE usuario = '$usuario'";
     $resultado=mysqli_query($con, $consulta);
     $con=mysqli_num_rows($resultado);
     if($con == 0){
        echo"Usuario inexistente. Introduzca un usuario registrado";
    }else{
        $tipo = "hidden"; //si el usuario existe el input pasa a ser de tipo oculto.
        $con=1;
    }
    echo"
    <form action='http://localhost/PROYECTO/pedirPlato.php'>
    <div class='boton'><input type=".$tipo." value='Vuelve'/></div>
    </form>
    ";
}
```

En caso de que quieras el boton tenerlo en html:

```
<input type="<?php echo $tipo; ?>" value="Vuelve" />
```

> He observado que tienes la variable `$con` después del `else`
>   comparandose con 1 y no sé si es un fallo en la redacción del código o
>   si es aproposito, pero si es para asignarle el valor 1 es: `$con=1;`.
>
> Y tambien he visto que no cierras la etiqueta `form`, pero como en la
>   anterior no se a que es debido y solo te informo, y me refiero a que
>   la etiqueta `form` no tiene `<` y debería ser `</form>`.

Comment: muchas gracias por los fallos y por lo de hidden que no lo sabia!